Is there a way to detect changes to JS `ArrayBuffer`?
I want to create an ArrayBuffer that functions like virtual memory: reads and writes to certain locations will translate to reads and writes at a different location in the "real" memory. I can filter reads and writes on a typed array (ex.: Uint8Array) to accomplish this for typed arrays, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler (and more robust) solution.
When I try to wrap ArrayBuffer in a Proxy before passing it into a typed array constructor, it doesn't work at all.

how is define your Proxy ? what do you mean by doesn't not work at all ?

Proxy is a completely valid solution to your problem, you need to include a [mcve] demonstrating your attempt to use one and whatever errors are produced.

@user229044: That might be overstating it a bit? I don’t think there’s any way to proxy a backing ArrayBuffer with an unaltered typed array (and thank goodness that’s the case, to be honest).

So you should proxy the typed array instead:


class ByteArray extends Uint8Array{
  constructor(...args){
    super(...args);
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(arr, prop){
        if((+prop).toString() === prop){
          console.log('getting byte at ' + prop);
        }
        return Reflect.get(...arguments);
      },
      set(arr, prop, val){
        if((+prop).toString() === prop){
          console.log('setting byte at ' + prop + ' to ' + val);
        }
        return Reflect.set(...arguments);
      }
    });
  }
}

const arr = new ByteArray(128);

arr[0] = 1;
console.log(arr[0]);



Note that a proxy is slow, so if you need a performance I suggest to access the array through overloaded methods:


class ByteArray extends Uint8Array{
  at(idx){
    console.log('getting byte at ' + idx);
    return super.at(idx);
  }
  setAt(idx, val){
    console.log('setting byte at ' + idx + ' to ' + val);
    this[idx] = val;
    return this;
  }
  set(arr, idx){
    arr.forEach((v, i) => this.setAt(idx+i, v));
  }
}

const arr = new ByteArray(128);

arr.setAt(0, 1);
arr.set([1,2,3],1);
console.log(arr.at(0));



